# when I import jsoup.jar in android ,there're some errors

Tags: android, jsoup

when I use jsoup.jar in android ,the problem is:

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: 
...
Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Couldn't the jsoup.jar used in android?
I search a lot materials, but it does't works!
Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have same jar library included twice. Check your application and all referenced Android libraries and make sure you have all jars included exactly once.